# get data from fetch array based on datetime element

Tags: php

I have a table

```
+---------------------+------+------+
| cdate               | src  | cnam |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2016-02-24 00:57:41 | 1111 | aaaa |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2016-02-24 00:58:33 | 2222 | bbbb |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2016-02-24 01:43:54 | 1111 | cccc |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2016-02-24 01:44:04 | 4444 | dddd |
+---------------------+------+------+
```

and I do select all data from that table..

```
$source = '1111';
$theDate = '2016-02-24';
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTb where src=".$source." and cdate >= '".$theDate." 00:00:00' AND cdate <= '".$theDate." 23:59:59' order by  cdate ASC");
```

So, I got all day in **$query**, now I need to loop in this array based on **cdate** for every 30 minutes..

---

**EDIT 1**

assume the datetime is `2016-02-24 00:15:00` and 2nd one is `2016-02-24 00:25:00` and the 3rd one is `2016-02-24 00:35:00` , I want to get the first two only, to calculate, then I move to the 3rd one, and so on.

---

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        if(**Condition**){

        }
    };
```

unfortunately I don't know what to type in **Condition** of IF!!

or if there any better idea.

thanks in advance

Comment: _" loop in this array based on cdate for every 30 minutes"_, what do you exactly mean by this part?

Comment: it's a datetime element, so.. I need to get the first 30 minutes and do some calculations, then the next 30 minutes, then. etc.. till the end of day, which is "2016-02-24"

Comment: First 30 minutes basing on the time of that date?, as an example, assume the date time is `2016-02-24 00:15:00`, you want to get `2016-02-24 00:45:00`?

Comment: assume the datetime is `2016-02-24 00:15:00` and 2nd one is `2016-02-24 00:25:00` and the 3rd one is `2016-02-24 00:35:00` , I want to get the first two only, to calculate, then I move to the 3rd one, and so on

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of trying, I got this :

```
if ($query){

    while( $row[] = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) );

    $PostStartopen = $theDate.' 00:00:00';
    $hh= 00;
    sprintf("%02d", $hh);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($row)-1; $i++) {

        for ($x = 1; $x <= 48; $x++) {
            $PostOpenDate = strtotime($PostStartopen.' + '.$hh.' minute');
            $hh += 30;
            $PostCloseDate = strtotime($PostStartopen.' + '.$hh.' minute');
            sprintf("%02d", $hh);

            if($PostOpenDate <= strtotime($row[$i]['calldate']) && $PostCloseDate > strtotime($row[$i]['calldate'])){
                // do stuff
                error_log($row[$i]['cdate']." NEEDED date to calculate");
            }

        }

        $PostStartopen = $theDate.' 00:00:00';
        $hh= 00;                    

    };


        echo json_encode(array("res" => "success","output" => $output)); 

} else {
        echo json_encode(array("res" => "error")); 
};
```

but I think there's a better way to do it..